# Can't use .find() function in a list from a Python Data Frame to find location of a character

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Kinda frustrating at the moment, here is the task at hand

I have a list of messages, these messages have a character "x", all before the character "x" must be deleted. The character "x" is found in different placements otherwise I'd just use a number.

```py
import pandas as pd
    
dbc = pd.read_csv(r'file1')
colDBC = [12]
dbc = dbc[dbc.columns[colDBC]]

ids = dbc.values
print (ids[0].find("x"))
```

Eventually, I'd like to run the `.find()` command in a loop, and use the value it sends to delete everything before the "x", any thoughts?

Comment: Use a regex: `dbc.str.replace('^(.*)x', '')`?

Answer (score 0):

Return highest indexes in each strings in the Series/Index.

> Each of returned indexes corresponds to the position where the
> substring is fully contained between [start:end]. Return -1 on
> failure. Equivalent to standard str.rfind().

```
 import pandas as pd
    
dbc = pd.read_csv(r'file1')
colDBC = [12]
dbc = dbc[dbc.columns[colDBC]]

ids = dbc.values
print (ids[0].rfind("x"))
```

Comment: This one returns a "'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'rfind'" error, am I importing the values within that column incorrectly?